# How to draw a polygon in google maps wrapping my points given a distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a set of points covering my city, lets call "gas stations" as example. I plotted all points om google maps. I need to draw a polygon, or several polygons, that represents the region covered by those gas stations within a 10km distance. My purpose is to find out regions that needs a gas station near by.

Comment: So you want to draw a circle around each gasstation/marker with a 10km radius with the center being a gasstation/marker?

Comment: Isn't expensive? I have around 1600 points, and i need to plot those all. There is no magic formula to calculate a poligon to simplify the overhead proccess?

Comment: So you are looking to only draw the outer ranges of all merged circles? My first guess is impossible without drawing the circles first.

Comment: Yes, only the outer ranges of all merged circles. Would be better if i could do all the calculation in background and plot only one polygon.

Comment: If I have polygon and i want to allocate stations , how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this => http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/circle-overlay/circle-overlay.html

I'm using it in my app. It's easy to use and provided by google itself !

Check http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery.html to get more examples of cool stuff for GMaps V3

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the harvesine-formula to measure the distance from your actual position to each other gas station and then search for the closest near by gas station.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by add a circle on top of the map at the same point as the gas stations

```
var circle_options = {
    map: map,
    center: location,
    radius: 16093 // 10 miles converted ot meters
};
circle = new google.maps.Circle(circle_options);
```

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Circles